# OpenCV-Python not recording with threaded setup for some reason

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, save

So the main part of my Bachelor-Work is to make an application that records from multiple cameras/devices at once. I started using OpenCV for this reason, and the extremely simple example works great. However when I tried to implement threading and multiple cameras for some reason it doesn't save the file. I don't get any error messages, the file simply doesn't appear. I'll post both the script that works (which is basically the same that can be found in all the online tutorials), and the relevant part of my code that doesn't work. Please let me know if you have any ideas as to why it doesn't work.

Working code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')    #Codec
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 24.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)

    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):  #No idea what this does...
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Problematic code:

```
class PreviewBox():

def __init__(self, capture):
    self.selected = False
    self.label = QLabel()
    self.label.mousePressEvent = self.toggleSelected
    self.cap = capture
    self.resizeFactor = 0.5
    self.interactable = True
    self.name = "defaultCam"
    return super().__init__()

def toggleSelected(self, event):
    if self.interactable == True:
        self.selected = not self.selected
        if self.selected == True :
            self.resizeFactor = 0.25
        else:
            self.resizeFactor = 0.5
#============================================================
class RecordingWindow(QWidget):

previews = []
previewThread = None
recordingThread = None

def __init__(self, mainWindow):
    super().__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_recordingTutorialWidget()
    self.mainWindow = mainWindow
    self.initUI()
    self.show()

def initUI(self):

    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.gridLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
    self.ui.startRecordingButton.clicked.connect(self.startRecording)
    self.ui.stopRecordingButton.clicked.connect(self.stopRecording)

def refreshPreviews(self):

    if self.previewThread is not None:
        self.previewThread.kill()

    for previewB in self.previews:
        previewB.interactable = False
        previewB.resizeFactor = 0.5
        self.ui.previewGrid.addWidget(previewB.label)

    self.previewThread = PreviewThread(self.previews)
    self.previewThread.daemon = True
    self.previewThread.start()

def startRecording(self):
    self.recordingThread = RecordingThread(self.previews)
    self.recordingThread.daemon = True
    self.recordingThread.start()

def stopRecording(self):
    self.recordingThread.kill()
#------------------------------------------------------------
class RecordingThread(threading.Thread):

outputs = []
doRun = True

def __init__(self, previews):
     super().__init__()
     for cam in previews:
         fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')    #Codec
         self.outputs.append((cam.cap, cv2.VideoWriter(cam.name, fourcc, 24.0, (int(cam.cap.get(3)),int(cam.cap.get(4))))))    #Output format and name

def run(self):
    while(self.doRun):
        for cap, output in self.outputs:
            if(cap.isOpened()):
                ret, frame = cap.read()  #Capture frame (ret is a boolean if frame is read succesfully)
                output.write(frame)
                print(ret)

    for cap, output in self.outputs:
        output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def kill(self):
    self.doRun = False
```

(I know the indendation is wrong here, it's because of pasting, it is correct in the actual editor. I'm just lazy.. :D )

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so surprise surprise, I was stupid. I forgot to add the file extension to the default name, and because of that it wasn't saving anything. Change the row where the videowriter is created to the following:

```
self.outputs.append((cam.cap, cv2.VideoWriter(cam.name+".avi", fourcc, 24.0, (int(cam.cap.get(3)),int(cam.cap.get(4))))))
```